# Is reverse email obfuscator from a website possible in any way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping, python-3.5

My program do webscrape on a website called [www.bizfeira.com](http://www.bizfeira.com). There is many compannies, with their contacts, for example:
http://www.bizfeira.com/pt/empresas/vitor-hugo-pais-unipessoal-lda/
if you move to "Contactos", you will see the email, and telephone, but this is with text obfuscator, and I have no idea how to reverse the email or even the telephone (telefone, or telemovel).
if anyone know a website with docomentation or know a solucion i would be greatfull.
There is the html code:

```
    <div class="directories-details-col-left">E-mail:</div>
                    <div class="directories-details-col-right"><a href="mailto:Z2VyYWxAbWVkaWdsb2JhbC5wdA==" class="text-obfuscator">Z2VyYWxAbWVkaWdsb2JhbC5wdA==</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double `==` sign on the end of that looks suspiciously like base64-encoded data...

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode("Z2VyYWxAbWVkaWdsb2JhbC5wdA==")
b'geral@mediglobal.pt'
```

Comment: Nice catch @Tom Dalton

Comment: I do have some semi-ethical worries about *why* that website is 'obfuscating' emails in this way... I assume it would be to prevent scripting-type email harvesting, but then why would you put the base64 email on the site at all?

Comment: given the fact it took you a few seconds to solve that problem you are correct, if that was their intention that is quite dumb. However even if it wasn't obfuscated, scraping a website is an ethical problem anyway without their consent

Comment: Interesting. I tend to think that it's public information and so scraping it isn't much different than paying (lots of) people to load the website on your behalf. It might be against specific terms of service if you have a registered account with them and are using that account/credentials to access non-public data.

Comment: Incidentally, I just checked the website http://www.bizfeira.com/pt/empresas/vitor-hugo-pais-unipessoal-lda/ and if you go to the contact details tab, the email address is rendered there as an image, so I think it's reasonable in this case to treat it as public. I will be able to sleep ok tonight :)

Comment: i mean why would they put the contacts on a website if not to contact the company?